# Fedora 31 cannot use Courier 10 Pitch

Tags: fedora, upgrade, fonts

I have recently updated to Fedora 31, but I cannot use the "Courier 10 Pitch" font in the system. I have installed the `xorg-x11-fonts-Type1` package from `dnf`, and the `fc-list` command gives me the correct files used by the font:

```
$ fc-list | grep Courier
/usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/c0611bt_.pfb: Courier 10 Pitch:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/c0419bt_.pfb: Courier 10 Pitch:style=Regular
/usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/c0583bt_.pfb: Courier 10 Pitch:style=Bold
/usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/c0582bt_.pfb: Courier 10 Pitch:style=Italic
$
```

But if I go to preference setting of gnome-terminal or gedit, I cannot find this font. I also cannot find the font in LibreOffice Writer.

I tried to use a live image, and it is the same result. Why is this happening? Is there a way to fix it?

To reproduce: boot from live image, and: `sudo dnf install xorg-x11-fonts-Type1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1779123, an workaround I am using is converting the font files manually to otf format. Here is the shell script I am using:

```
for i in {0419,0582,0583,0611}; do
    fontforge -c 'open(argv[1]).generate(argv[2])' \
        /usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/c${i}bt_.pfb c${i}bt_.otf;
done
sudo mkdir /usr/share/fonts/courier/
sudo mv c{0419,0582,0583,0611}bt_.otf /usr/share/fonts/courier/
sudo fc-cache -v
```